# How do you measure distance from a line end point to a point on a separate layer in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, line, distance

I have layer of points that correspond to a layer of lines.  I need to find the distance from the beginning and end point of the line to the corresponding point.  I used line_locate_point to get the distance from the start point but I can not figure out how to calculate the distance from the end point.   Here's what I have for the start point.

```
line_locate_point(geometry:=geometry(get_feature('path','Jct_ID',"Point Code")),point:=$geometry)
```

[image]

Comment: That's just *line length minus distance to start point*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate `Distance of whole line - distance from the start point` (pseudocode) - use this expression:

```
length (geometry(get_feature('path','Jct_ID',"Point Code")))-
line_locate_point(geometry(get_feature('path','Jct_ID',"Point Code")),$geometry)
```

or, alternatively (where line 3 contains the expression for the line):

```
with_variable (
    'line',
    geometry(get_feature('path','Jct_ID',"Point Code")),
    length(@line) - line_locate_point(@line,$geometry))
```

Comment: Elegant and simple.  It didn't occur to me to just subtract the length.  Thank you very much.