# QGIS - Find point position on line (lengthwise)

Tags: qgis, point, line, distance, linear-referencing

I have a line layer with some lines, and a point layer whose points are located on those lines.

Now I need to get the position "along" the line where each point is (as in distance from start of the line along the line)

- A point located at the start of the line would be at `0 meters` from start
- A point at the end of the line would be at `<length> meters` from start
- A point anywhere in between would be calculated accordingly

I found two answers that can surely help me achieve this, but they're using Python, and I'm almost sure there is a very simple button or processing tool that would do this instead.

- [Length of line on specific point (from point layer)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226327/length-of-line-on-specific-point-from-point-layer)
- [How do you measure distance from a line end point to a point on a separate layer in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409591/how-do-you-measure-distance-from-a-line-end-point-to-a-point-on-a-separate-layer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the field calculator on the POINT_Layer. I don't think there is a one-click tool.

```
line_locate_point(aggregate('YOUR_LINE_LAYER_NAME','collect',$geometry),$geometry)
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT - Based on comment by [she_weeds](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/98784/she-weeds)**

The difference between the two methodes `aggregate/collect` and `overlay_nearest` can be seen if you have two lines in the line layer.

`aggregate/collect` count the distance along both lines and `overlay_nearest` starts with 0 at the beginning of each line.

```
line_locate_point(overlay_nearest('YOUR_LINE_LAYER_NAME',$geometry)[0], $geometry)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: An alternative to this is using `line_locate_point(overlay_nearest('YOUR_LINE_LAYER_NAME',$geometry)[0], $geometry)` so that each point has its distance measured along the closest line, rather than a collection of all the line layers' features

Comment: @she_weeds tried to improve answer on your comment

Comment: Any way to return this in meters? (my current projection is in degrees)

Comment: @DanielMöller you would be much better off using a projected CRS to begin with, but if you must work in degrees, you could adapt the expression by wrapping any instance of `$geometry` with `transform()` to convert from a degree-based CRS to an appropriate meter-based CRS.